# Looping FileReader

Tags: java, loops, filereader

I have to read a text file line by line, except after 7 lines I want to use what's read by assigning the 7 lines to 7 different variables. Once I've assigned them, I want to use the variables. That is the easy part, which I know how to do, what has me stuck is that after I have used the 7 variables, I want to be able to assign the next 7 lines of my text file to the same variables, and use them again. I know I have to use loop(s), but ,

- how do I make it stop after 7 lines instead of just re-assigning the lines to the variables?
- Should I use 2 loops?
- Or is there something similar to a break or maybe some sort of "pause" I can apply?
- Or is there a some sort of counter that can be used with the FileReader class?
- Or should I create one?

Here is what our teacher wants.

---

Parking Tickets

What to Do:
This assignment is based on Programming Challenge problem-8 on page 574 with some revisions so read this handout carefully. You are allowed to work in teams of 2 people if you desire. The collaboration and discussion would be helpful. Note: This is the longest and likely the most difficult program of the course so work carefully and follow the instructions.

For this assignment you will design a set of classes that work together to simulate a parking officer issuing parking tickets to some cars parked at meters. The problem may be a little artificial when compared to how real meters and tickets work.

You will design four separate classes and a demo program to run everything. Read this whole assignment to the end before starting to write Java code. You need to understand the structure of several classes and understand how the data file is organized.

The basic setting is a group of parking meters with cars parked at them for different amounts of time.

Each car will have purchased some parking time recorded in minutes. And each car will have parked for a certain length of time also recorded in minutes. Some will have parked for more time than they purchased and some for less time than purchased.

Here are the four classes you are required to develop.
•   The ParkedCar Class: This class should simulate a parked car. The class’s responsibilities are as follows:
-   To know the car’s make, model, color, license number 
-   To know the identity number of its parking meter.
-   Has a toString() method to report its identifying information

•   The ParkingMeter Class: This class will simulate a parking meter. The class’s responsibility is as follows:
-   to know its own meter identity number
-   To know the number of minutes that have been purchased
-   To know the number of minutes parked
-   has a toString() method to report its information

•   The ParkingOfficer Class: This class should simulate a parking officer inspecting parked cars. The class’s responsibilities are as follows:
-   Has two instance variables: one for name and one for badge number of the officer
-   Has a constructor with two parameters for the parking officer’s name and badge number
-   Has a toString() method 
-   Has an examine() method which receives a ParkedCar object, and a ParkingMeter object as parameters. This method determines whether the time has expired or not
   If time has expired it creates a parking ticket object which is returned as the return value from examine().
   If time has not expired it returns null.

•   The ParkingTicket Class: This class will simulate a parking ticket. The class’s responsibility is as follows:
-   Has a constructor which receives as parameters a ParkedCar object, a ParkingMeter object and a ParkingOfficer object which are used to initialize corresponding instance variables in the class. Be sure to use copy constructors for each of these parameter objects.
-   This class also has an instance variable for the amount of fine.
-   The fine is calculated by the ParkingTicket constructor:
   The fine is $25 for the first hour or part of an hour that the car is illegally parked, plus $10 for every additional hour or part of an hour that the car is illegally parked. 
   If time has not expired the fine is set to zero.
-   Has a toString() method which prepares the ticket in a useful format of your design (try to match the sample output shown below or make your own improvements. It must report the make, model, color, and license number of an illegally parked car. It also reports the amount of the fine and the name and badge number of the police officer issuing the ticket. In this toString() method you must make effective use of the toString() methods for the other classes in parking ticket (i.e. the ParkedCar, the ParkingMeter, and the ParkingOfficer)

Testing Class
Write a testing class, TicketDemo, with main() to run the simulation using the above classes as follows:
•   Create a PoliceOfficer object. Make up your own name and badge number. You may hard-wire this into your test program or ask the user for input data (your choice).
•   In a loop read data from the data file Asg-5_in.txt. (Note:  the file Asg-5_inExplain.txt describes how to interpret the file content.)
o   Read one block of data for a car and a meter and create a ParkedCar object and a ParkingMeter object
o   Call the parking officer examine() method using your ParkedCar and Parking meter objects as arguments. The examine method will return a ticket or null.
o   If a ticket is returned, call the toString() method to print the ticket on the screen.
o   If no ticket is issued print identification information about the car (use its toString() method.
o   Let the loop repeat until there is no more data available from the input file.

---

Here is what I have so far, although I'm nowhere near being done.

ParkedCar class:

```
public class ParkedCar{

private String make;
private String model;
private String color;
private String license;
private String meterID;

public String getMake(String make)
{
    this.make = make;
    return make;
}

public String getModel(String model)
{
    this.model = model;
    return model;
}

public String getColor(String color)
{
    this.color = color;
    return color;
}

public String getLicense(String license)
{
    this.license = license;
    return license;
}

public String getMeterID(String meterID)
{
    this.meterID = meterID;
    return meterID;
}

public String toString()
{
    String str = "\nMake: " + make + "\nModel: " + model + "\nColor: " + color +
                 "\nLicense: " + license + "\nMeter ID: " + meterID;
    return str;
}
}
```

ParkingMeter class:

```
public class ParkingMeter{

private String meterID;
private int minsPurchased;
private int minsParked;

public String getMeterID(String meterID)
{
    this.meterID = meterID;
    return meterID;
}

public int getMinsPurchased(int minsPurchased)
{
    this.minsPurchased = minsPurchased;
    return minsPurchased;
}

public int getColor(int minsParked)
{
    this.minsParked = minsParked;
    return minsParked;
}

public String toString()
{
    String str = "\nMeter ID: " + meterID + "\nMinutes Purchased: " + minsPurchased +
                 "\nMinutes Parked: " + minsParked;
    return str;
}
}
```

ParkingOfficer class:

```
public class ParkingOfficer{

private String officerName;
private String badgeNumber;

public ParkingOfficer(String officerName, String badgeNumber)
{
    this.officerName = officerName;
    this.badgeNumber = badgeNumber;
}

public ParkingOfficer(ParkingOfficer object2)
{
    officerName = object2.officerName;
    badgeNumber = object2.badgeNumber;
}


public void setParkingOfficer(String officerName, String badgeNumber)
{
    this.officerName = officerName;
    this.badgeNumber = badgeNumber;
}

public String toString()
{
    String str = "\nOfficer's Name: " + officerName + "\nOfficer's Badge Number: " + badgeNumber;
    return str;
}

}
```

Comment: Or is there a some sort of counter that can be used with the FileReader class? Or should I create one?

Comment: Can you post you attempt so that we may help you extend it.

Comment: Tag this as homework, please.  It wasn't clear when it was first posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic structure would be something like this:

```
while (true) {
  String v1 = reader.readLine();
  if (v1 == null)
    break;
  String v2 = reader.readLine();
  ...
  String v7 = reader.readLine();
  /* Do what ever you want with v1 through v7. */
  ...
}
/* End of loop. */
```

Comment: I thought I understood this concept, except your if statement confused me... Why would I be using it at this time, and what is the result of the break in this situation? The only time I've ever really used break is in a switch statement...

Comment: @lovinbayb4e: I assume that you're using the `BufferedReader` class so that you can use its `readLine()` method. If so, at the end of the file, `readLine()` will return `null`. Inside the loop, I'm testing that condition. So, at the beginning of each loop (which I'm guessing represents a single record), test to see if there's another record. If there is, continue to read; otherwise, `break` out of the loop. The `break` statement is what terminates to looping at the end of the file.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the thing is that the file is 42 lines long... I want to use the lines that are read in blocks of 7, 6 times.

Comment: @lovinbayb4e: Right, so each time through the loop, you'll read 7 lines. The loop should execute completely 6 times. Then, when it attempts to read line 43, `readLine()` will return `null`, which will stop the looping. Execution will then continue at `/* End of loop. */`

Answer (score 4):

```
int lineCounter = 0;
int variableCounter = 7;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("your-file-here.txt")));
String line = "";
List<String> lineSavers = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    lineSavers.add(line);
    ++lineCounter;
    if (lineCounter == variableCounter) {
        // do something with the lineSaver
        lineSavers.clear();
        linteCounter = 0;
        // start the cycle again.
    }
}
```

There's a lot of stuff that I didn't consider here:

1. Cleaning up resources - I didn't close the reader.
2. What happens if you read a file whose line count isn't evenly divided by 7.  You'll never get those last lines the way I wrote it.
3. Hard coded variable counter.  I'd make that a variable to be passed in.
4. Not very modular; I'd pass in that file name and encapsulate the whole thing in a method.
5. I'd try a more functional approach where I'd pass back what I wanted and then operate on it rather than mingle reading and processing together.
6. Why seven lines?  What are you doing with them?  Are they really related in a way that'd be better expressed as an object?  You're probably not thinking about the problem in the best way.

Comment: It's for a college assignment... I've already created 3 classes: ParkedCar, ParkingMeter, and ParkingOfficer; I'm working on the 4th: ParkingTicket. They all compile with no errors, but I have to read the lines of a file he gave us, and use them throughout the classes. The file reads, in order, the car make, model, color, and license, the parking meter ID, the minutes purchased, and how many minutes the car has been parked. Then the ParkingOfficer class checks if the time is expired. If it is, a ticket is given and if not it returns void. I have to repeat this 6 times.

Comment: I'd separate reading the file from all this logic and processing.  Read the file into appropriate objects and data structures, close the file, and operate on those objects and data structures.  Don't mingle the two.  It's called "single responsibility": give a method or class a single thing to do.

Comment: So you're saying I should read everything..? But I don't understand how I'm supposed to do that... I don't want 42 different variables, I only want 7 and then replace those 7 values with the next 7... I don't know why I'm having so much trouble grasping this concept... It's probably so simple and I'm just over-thinking it all...

Comment: Reading and processing are two separate steps.  I'm sure that reading all of them isn't taxing memory much.  From your point of view, what's the difference between a file and a data structure?  The latter is in memory, where you can get at it easily.  Iterating over a list of strings will be separate from reading them into memory if you do it as I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

You could use commons-io to read the file in one go, and then loop over the list. A bit of example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Read the content of the file in one go
  InputStream input = null;
  // This is where the file content is stored
  List<String> lines = null; 
  try {
    input = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
    lines = IOUtils.readLines(new BufferedInputStream(input));
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    // Always (try to) close the file
    if (input != null) {
      try {
        input.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  if (lines != null) {
    String[] params = null; // per 7 lines
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
      int fromZeroToSixCounter = i % 7; 
      if ( fromZeroToSixCounter == 0 ) { 
        if (params != null) { 
          // the first time (i == 0) params is null and this will not execute
          doSomethingWithParams(params);
        }
        // new batch of 7 lines
        params = new String[7];
      }
      params[fromZeroToSixCounter] = lines.get(i);
    }
    if (params != null) {
      // the last batch 
      doSomethingWithParams(params);
    }
  }
}

public static void doSomethingWithParams(String[] params) {
  System.out.println("New batch");
  for (int i=0; i < params.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(params[i]);
  }
}
```